# EF Many to Many: A has many B's, B doesn't need to know

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Say I have the following. Note that Category doesn't need to have a reference to the projects it's associated with. Is there a way to configure this, or does convention dictate that I should be throwing a collection of Projects in my Category model?

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

There are a few similar questions around but the answers don't seem to address it.

Update:
As I thought, I do need to have that intermediate table, but EF does it for me by following Moho's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasMany( p => p.Categories )
    .WithMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
.HasMany(p => p.Categories)
.WithMany() 
.Map(m =>
{
    m.MapLeftKey("Id");
    m.MapRightKey("Id");
    m.ToTable("ProjectsCategories");
});
```